# SQL Trigger for when a inserted or updated value is too high or low

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a trigger that runs when a car price that's inserted or updated is too high or low.
When trying to compile it just says identifier must be declared where other similar methods I have used or seen use the same methods.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER carlistprice_insert_update 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON car
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.carlistprice < 0 OR NEW.carlistprice > 250000)
BEGIN
        IF NEW.carlistprice < 0 THEN
        :NEW.carlistprice := 0;
        END IF;
        IF NEW.carlistprice > 250000 THEN
        :NEW.carlistprice := 250000;
        END IF;
END;
/
```

**I am basing this program off of this block of code which works and doesn't need identifier declared.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(NEW.custname != UPPER(NEW.custname))
BEGIN
    :NEW.custname := UPPER(:NEW.custname);
END;
/
```

**The carlistprice is a valid column in one of my tables**

Answer (score 1):

- in `WHEN` clause, `NEW` (as well as `OLD`) is without a colon.
- elsewhere, it has to be preceded by a colon

So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER carlistprice_insert_update 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON car
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.carlistprice < 0 OR NEW.carlistprice > 250000)  -- no colon here
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.carlistprice  < 0 THEN                   -- colon here
     :NEW.carlistprice := 0;                       -- and here
  END IF;

  IF :NEW.carlistprice  > 250000 THEN              -- and here
     :NEW.carlistprice := 250000;                  -- and here
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: I was so close, thanks for pointing that out. I appreciate the response!

Comment: Just be aware that this often can confuse an end user, because they type 26,000 on screen and then 25,000 comes back.  If you have validation at the front end as well, then perhaps rather than a trigger, a better database approach is not a trigger but a constraint to make sure nothing has slipped through, ie,  `alter table car add constraint car_chk check ( carlistprice between 0 and 25000 )`